# Database migration from dev to production in Graphcool

Tags: database-migration, graphql, graphcool

I have a mobile app frontend using Graphcool as the backend. I currently have two Graphcool project, one for production and the other one for dev. Now I need to migrate the dev version of the database to the production one. To be specific, I need to do the followings:

1. Update ENUM
2. Update Schema and make sure it won't break the current data
3. Update the permission and rules
4. Update functions

I have tried to copy and paste the new schema from dev to production, but I find out there are many inconsistencies I need to solve manually. Meanwhile, since the project export function currently has no way to backup the permissions and functions, I have to manually change them once step 1 and 2 are finished.

The question is my production project has many live requests and I don't want to have any down time or requests that potentially can break data consistency. What will be the best way to deal with this kind of migration? Are there any guidelines, best practises? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since I last asked the question, Graphcool has posted a doc to introduce the multi staging workflow. The new cli has included most of the questions I asked.

https://www.graph.cool/docs/tutorials/cli-multi-staging-workflow-ex4wo4zaep/